# Create new user with Names , Username etc in firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm new android learner so its is difficult for me to do stuffs which I cannot find in the documentation. Here is my code for creating users

```java
 mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                        //Successfully Registered
                        Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Registration Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }else {
                        //Error occurred during registration
                        Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Registration Unsuccessful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        try {
                            throw task.getException();
                        } catch(FirebaseAuthWeakPasswordException e) {
                            editTextPassword.setError(e.getMessage());
                            editTextPassword.requestFocus();
                        }catch(FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException | FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException e) {
                            editTextEmail.setError(e.getMessage());
                            editTextEmail.requestFocus();
                        } catch(Exception e) {
                            Log.e(RegisterActivity.class.getName(), e.getMessage());
                        }
                    }
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
```

This only takes two parameters(email and password) to create an user. To create user with more fields what approach should I take.

I have also added a `FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener()` to check user login status. But when I'm calling `firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getDisplayName()` after successfully user login it returns `null` as usual.So how can I create user with Names so I can retrieve it with `firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getDisplayName()`.

Comment: Have you tried, 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#update_a_users_profile

Comment: @srijanshukla thanks for providing the documentation link. Actually I didn't knew the right approach.

Comment: Can anyone tell me which is a good practice among these two answers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the registration is successful,

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

UserProfileChangeRequest profileUpdates = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
        .setDisplayName("Jane Q. User")
        .build();
```

---

**EDIT:** This code is a bit incomplete as `profileUpdates` is never accessed.

```
user.updateProfile(profileUpdates)
    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "User profile updated.");
             }
         }
     });
```

---

Then, to retrieve it, use this wherever required,

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
if (user != null) {
    // Name, email address etc
    String name = user.getDisplayName();
    String email = user.getEmail();
}
```

Comment: It will always give null pointer exception for getDisplayName();

Comment: @kshitijjain but there is an if condition already to check against it

Comment: There seems to be a delay in retrieving the updated displayName. I thought it would be stable within onComplete() and you can't get anything interesting in the task returned since it is of type Void. Is there an easy work-around?

Answer (score 3):

To add a user with extra information such as User's name or other required information you should store these data using the Firebase real-time database under the unique user_id generated upon successful completion of email and password registration.

Get user input for name in registration form,

```
String name = mNameField.getText().toString().trim();
```

Add user's name in `onComplete` method :

```
 @Override
 public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
 if(task.isSuccessful()){

     String user_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid;

     DatabaseReference current_user = mDatabase.child(user_id);

     current_user.child("name").setValue(name);

     progressDialog.dismiss();

  }
```

Comment: What modification can be done to the rules rules to give access to write under the `uid` node during registration rather setting  `".read": true,  ".write": true`.
Let us assume my tree structure root-->users-->uid-->name @ramithdr